# In a grails gsp template, how can I use a server side comment without sitemesh throwing an error?

Tags: templates, grails, gsp, sitemesh

When I use a standard jsp comment block in a gsp template

```
<%-- some server-side comment --%>
```

, sitemesh throws an 'unexpected token' error.  Is there another comment syntax I can use?

Comment: To clarify, the <%-- syntax works in a gsp but not in a gsp template being included with <g:render.

Comment: Question was for Grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular java comment block will work

```
<% /*  some server side comment */ %>
```

Comment: its not good approach in gsp pages.
use %{-- --}% that is truly created for gsp pages

Answer (score 26):

The following works for me

```
%{-- <div>hello</div> --}%
```

Answer (score 19):

You are missing a '%' sign. Write it as :

```
<%-- some server-side comment --%>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Typo was just in the question, not the code, question fixed.

Answer (score 5):

The original question was asking how to comment out anything in the GSP file. The only one that worked for me is

`<%--  some code to comment out --%>`,

the other answers won't work especially if the code being commented are grails tags. %{ and <% didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

There's a little confusion among previous answers (and the question itself) that I wish was explained to me at first. There are a few types of server side comments on a .gsp.
So within the .gsp document Server side comments go as follow:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- the basic HTML comment (not on server side) -->
    <h1>Visible on client side</h1>

    <%-- GSP common comment (server side only) --%>
    %{-- GSP alternative approach (again, on server side only) --}%
    <g:if test="${true}">
        <h1>Invisible on client side, just in source code</h1>
    </g:if>

    <p>and the one asked for happens elsewhere, 
    whenever you write classic Groovy script</p>
    <g:set var="myTitle"/>
    <%
        myVar = 'comment'
        if(myVar.equals('comment')){
            /*Needs the classic Java comment, 
            this happens whether you're writing a simple .gsp 
            or any _template.gsp*/
            myTitle = "<h1>Visible on server side only</h1>".encodeAsRaw()
        }
    %>
    ${myTitle}

    <p>.gsp template does not modify comment behaviour</p>
    <g:render template="/templates/myTemplate" model="[:]"/>
</body>
</html>
```

file: _myTemplate.gsp

```
<h2>Template</h2>

<!-- visible -->
<% invisible %>
%{-- invisible --}%
<% /*invisible*/ %>
```

(Grails 2.5.5)

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing a gsp that wants to display a uninterpreted grails *g:* tag, e.g. you want *<g:link* ... to appear as-is on the page, without being interpreted server-side, the following worked nicely for me.

In both the start and end tags, replace the *<* with *&lt;*

e.g.

*<g:link...>...</g:link>* gets interpreted server-side and shows up in the page a link.

*&lt;g:link ...>...&lt;/g:link ...>* shows up in the front-end page as ***<g:link...>...</g:link>***

Answer (score 0):

`<%-- server side code --%>` should work